# Using Password Recovery control with my own database

Tags: asp.net

I want to use the password recovery control of asp.net, but with my own database, I dont want to use the membership table that is already provided. Is there a way to do this? I have searched on google but did not get a single one that is relevant to what I want to do. Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach to this would be to implement your own [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider(v=vs.100).aspx), this would allow you to override the default behaviour. However, you would need to implement *all* the behaviour, not just the stuff you want to change (see this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6tc47t75(v=vs.100).aspx)).

You can implement the [GetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getpassword(v=vs.100).aspx) / [ResetPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.security.membershipprovider.resetpassword(v=vs.100).aspx) methods and have them work from your own database rather than the membership table.

Comment: @sumedha these are factors you should take into account before deciding you want to do something custom. You might find it's not worth the effort.

Comment: yes I realized that,now I am doing it the normal way, as in without using the password recovery control